# OpenVPN client is not working on Windows computer?

Tags: linux, windows, centos, openvpn

I try to run my OpenVPN client on my windows 10 machine in order to connect to a remote OpenVPN CentOS 7 server but it does not work. I get the error below:

```
Options error: --capath fails with 'C:\Users\Desktop\OpenVPN\ca.crt': No such process (errno=3)
Options error: --cert fails with 'C:\Users\Desktop\OpenVPN\Win10client.crt': No such process (errno=3)
Fri Mar 22 22:56:20 2019 WARNING: cannot stat file 'C:\Users\Desktop\OpenVPN\Win10client.key': No such process (errno=3)
Options error: --key fails with 'C:\Users\Desktop\OpenVPN\Win10client.key'
Fri Mar 22 22:56:20 2019 WARNING: cannot stat file 'C:\Users\Desktop\OpenVPN\myvpn.tlsauth': No such process (errno=3)
Options error: --tls-crypt fails with 'C:\Users\Desktop\OpenVPN\myvpn.tlsauth': No such process (errno=3)
```

This is the config that I have on my ovpn file:

```
client
tls-client
--capath C:\\Users\\Desktop\\OpenVPN\\ca.crt
--cert C:\\Users\\Desktop\\OpenVPN\\Win10client.crt
--key C:\\Users\\Desktop\\OpenVPN\\Win10client.key
--tls-crypt C:\\Users\\Desktop\\OpenVPN\\myvpn.tlsauth

remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Client Authentication"
proto udp
remote serveraddress 1194 udp
dev tun
topology subnet
pull
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your config file is well done. Try to reinstall openvpn, and put your config file to the c:/program files/openvpn/config folder. Then you can start the openvpn Service. Therefore you dont need to use the Openvpn gui.